# Node.js os package installation fails

Tags: node.js

I need to install **os** package in my node.js program. I enter the following command:

> npm install os --save

and I receive:

> npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: os

Any clues about solving this issue?!

Thanks

Comment: That's because [it doesn't exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os). [os](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) is a built-in API, meaning you can just do `var os = require('os');`.

Comment: Thanks! along programming, sometimes world is turning around my head. It was one of those moments :D